# SQL convert single column to multiple row based on string pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have a table with the following sample data:

```
id, query
----------
25, normal query
25, query with brackets (example1) 
46, brackets in query (example2) (example3)
55, text1 (example4) text2
```

For the queries having brackets, I would like to add a row to the table with the information in every bracket as follows:

```
id, query
----------
25, normal query
25, query with brackets
25, example1
46, brackets in query
46, example2
46, example3
55, text1 text2
55, example4
```

I can easily identify the rows having brackets with `LIKE '%(%)%'`, however I'm not sure how to split and add new rows.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense for me. How do you handle correlated subqueries or nested ones(more than 2 levels)? How do you want to differentiate between function call and subquery?

Comment: Ah of course, for every text in brackets, I want to add a new row with the same id. I have made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  id,
  regexp_split_to_table(
    replace(query,')','')
  ,E'\\(') query
from TestTable
```

---

**Result:**

```
| id |                query |
|----|----------------------|
| 25 |         normal query |
| 25 | query with brackets  |
| 25 |             example1 |
| 46 |   brackets in query  |
| 46 |            example2  |
| 46 |             example3 |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e2f7a/27/0)

---

#### For New Question :

> Thank you!! Can you please help with the new row 55? I've made an edit to the question and required output.

```
select 
  id,
  regexp_split_to_table(
    replace(
      replace(
        replace(
          query
          ,') (','(')        
        ,') ','( ')
    ,')','')
  ,E'\\(') query
from TestTable
```

---

**Result:**

```
| id |                query |
|----|----------------------|
| 25 |         normal query |
| 25 | query with brackets  |
| 25 |             example1 |
| 46 |   brackets in query  |
| 46 |             example2 |
| 46 |             example3 |
| 55 |               text1  |
| 55 |             example4 |
| 55 |                text2 |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d8d22/4/0)

Comment: Thank you!! Can you please help with the new row `55`? I've made an edit to the question and required output.

Comment: hmmm... thank you so much for your troubles! But it does not give the desired output for `55` as `55, text1 text2` and `55, example4` :( Basically only the text in brackets should be removed not the text infront or before...